# Priority in Testng project

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, testng

Suppose if have 1000 test priority and already sequenced, but I need one new test priority between 500 to 501 test case, so how add new priority between 500 and 501?

So I renamed the priority count after 502 to till 1000 test cases or any other way we can solve?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same priority and add alphabetic ordering to the method name.

@Test(priority=500)
public void a_method(){}

@Test(priority=500)
public void b_method(){}